# Live server and browsers combine my divs into 1 when Inside code I have 2 divs separately

Tags: html, css

So in my code I have 2 divs that exists inside a Parent div. When I open the code with live server or from the file folder and inspect it in google or mozilla for some reason my divs were combined into the other div.

Why does it do that? By the way I'm trying to align the search div to the right (school task)

**HTML BELOW**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="teht14.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="base">


          <div id="links">
            <a href="https://www.savonia.fi/">Savonia (linkki)</a>
            <select name="" id="">
              <option value="">Valitse</option>
              <option value="">Ohjeet</option>
              <option value="">Yhteystiedot</option>
          </div>     
      
          <div id="search">
            <form method="get" id="search">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
              <input type="submit" value="Search">
            </form>
          </div>


        </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**CSS BELOW**

```
    #base {
        display: flex;
        background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
        padding: 3em 0 3em 0;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

I am expecting that the divs are separated in the browser as it is in the code but mainly I am trying to align the search div to the right. This is a school task.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a closing `<select>` tag. Some browsers try to correct the error and depending on what it is, respond differently. That is why you were seeing what you were seeing.

Below is what your code should be. Good luck.

```css
#base {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgb(196, 196, 196);
  padding: 3em 0 3em 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="teht14.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="base">

    <div id="links">
      <a href="https://www.savonia.fi/">Savonia (linkki)</a>
      <select name="" id="">
        <option value="">Valitse</option>
        <option value="">Ohjeet</option>
        <option value="">Yhteystiedot</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div id="search">
      <form method="get" id="search">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <input type="submit" value="Search">
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```